# Can I link memberships to relationships automatically?

Tags: civimember, civireport, relationships

I'm using CiviCRM to manage sponsors of children in India for an NGO. I'm configured it and set up some custom fields in order to have the children(contact) connected to the membership.

So far so good, I can generate reports to see payments due, etc.

The problem is, I can not work the other way around, that is, seeing which children don't have sponsors.

My guess to solve this was to use Relationships, as I could then report and filter on that. But I've not been able to automatically create a relationship between sponsor-child when adding the membership. (doing it manually would be really tiring for the people who manage this).

Is it possible?
Any other ideas on how I could go about this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can set type of relationship to be used for a membership type. So when a membership is purchased the contact will have relationship with the organization automatically and also will be set to inactive when membership is expired or cancelled.

[image]

You can also check documentation for more information at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/defining-memberships/ (search keyword - Relationship Type)

Comment: I saw that, but it doesnt seem to fit for my needs. I dont want a relationship with an "organization" but with another contact. The relationship start and end date should also match the membership dates

Comment: The question asks about creating a relationship when a membership is created.  The option highlighted above uses existing relationships but does not create relationships.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Drupal then you can create Relationships at same time as Membership purchase via the Webform CiviCRM module